# Using an ES6 class: how do you call a method from within an event-handler?

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener

in following code

```
<button type="button" id="btnLogMsg">Press me</button>

<script>
class Logger {

    constructor() {     
        this.log("msg 1");          // logs 'msg 1': OK

        this.btnLogMsg = document.getElementById("btnLogMsg");
        this.btnLogMsg.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            console.log("msg 2");       // logs 'msg 2': OK
            log("msg 3");               // ERROR
            this.log("msg 3");          // ERROR
        });
    }  // ctor

    log(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }           
} // class Logger

var logger = new Logger();
```

When loading the html-file, output is

msg 1

When pressing the button, output is

msg 2

But not

msg 2

msg 3

Nor
    log("msg 3");
nor 
    this.log("msg 3");
work.

Examining  this.log("3");
  I know that 'this' refers to the clicked button, hence btnLogMsg.
  So, invoking this.log() is not possible.

But how then?

Thank you
Chris

Answer (score 2):

you have quite a few options. Your problem is, that your scope within your function differs from the scope outside of your function, which is why `this` in the function is not the same as `this` outside the function.

As you mentioned es6, the easiest way is to use an [arrow-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like so:

```
this.btnLogMsg.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    console.log("msg 2");       // logs 'msg 2': OK
    this.log("msg 3");          // should now work
});
```

Another way to make this work would be to save a pointer to the outer `this`, and use that instead:

```
var self = this;
this.btnLogMsg.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    console.log("msg 2");       // logs 'msg 2': OK
    self.log("msg 3");          // should now work
});
```

a third way that should work is to bind the outer-scope to the inner function (this has the same effect as using an arrow-function):

```
this.btnLogMsg.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    console.log("msg 2");       // logs 'msg 2': OK
    this.log("msg 3");          // should now work
}.bind(this));
```

you should read a little about scopes and [this in different contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Just wondering: why a down vote on my question? Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @ChrisPeeters i didn't downvote, but i'd guess your question could have been formatted better, and you could've told us what you tried, what you googled, and why your research you did before asking here didn't yield any results

Comment: Ok. I'll use your advice next time I have a question. Thx